# Stack Overflow Exception in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Thread. I have created two classes name A and B as follow-

```
public class A {

    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    synchronized void foo() {
        b.foo();
        System.out.println("Hi A");
    }
}

public class B {

    private A a;

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    synchronized void foo() {
        a.foo();
        System.out.println("Hi B");
    }
}
```

Now i have created two other classes which implements Runnable interface.

```
public class AThread implements Runnable{
    private A a;
    public AThread(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        a.foo();
    }

}

public class BThread implements Runnable {
    private B b;
    public BThread(B a){
        this.b = b;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        b.foo();
    }

}
```

In main method, i have written the following code-

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.setB(b);
        b.setA(a);
        Runnable r1 = new AThread(a);
        Runnable r2 = new BThread(b);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        t1.start();

    }
```

When i am running this code, i got the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at student.B.foo(B.java:21)
    at student.A.foo(A.java:21)..
```

Can any one explain what is the route cause of it and how can i solve it?

Comment: you get infinite recursive call sequences when you call `foo()` method of your objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What did you expect?

You have a `foo()` method in `A` calling the `foo()` method in `B` that called the `foo()` method in `A`, and so on, until the stack overflows.

You can solve it by avoiding circular method calls.

Comment: Some one has given me this problem and told me how can we make it Thread safe?

Comment: Is this any tricky question? i am new to thread. I assumed that it is DeadLock situation.

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal It is not a deadlock. It is a circular call, as Eran mentioned. If you have another question, you should ask it in a new post.

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal Why did you expect a deadlock? You are running these circular calls in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a function, the stack saves the adress of the function it has been called from, and only removes it once the function has been completed. In A.foo you call B.foo, and in B.foo you call A.foo. So your stack fills itself with the adresses of B.foo and A.foo. The loop never ends but the size of your stack does. So i suggest trying to elminate the endless loop. Can't tell you how because I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, the `StackOverflowError` has nothing to do with threads. Perhaps a simplified example can make this clearer.

It can be reproduced using the following code which does not contain any `Thread`s:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.setB(b);
    b.setA(a);
    a.foo();
}
```

`A.foo` calls `B.foo` which calls `A.foo` which... eventually leads to a stack overflow. There is only a single `Thread` involved, here the main thread, in your example `t1`. You are never executing the `Runnable r2` at all.

To address your suspicion from [the comments on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025689/stack-overflow-exception-in-java/44025749#comment75077960_44025749):
A deadlock can only occur if multiple threads try to acquire the same locks, and it would not lead to an Exception - typically, the effect of a deadlock is that nothing happens at all, the locked threads never terminate.